# Line of white space on first line of an XML string

Tags: php, xml, xmlwriter

I have a little problem with a string that I am outputting to an XML reader, the first line of the string is a line of white space and I can't seem to get rid of it , when I try to read the string it is giving me this error because of the line of white space at the very top.

```
Error on line 5 of document: 
The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed. 
Nested exception: 
The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed."
```

Comment: can you attach the XML document?

Comment: The error is clear and that you see it is correct because there is an error with the document. What is your concrete programming question with that error? How is this question related to XMLWriter (per tag) when in your text you write about XMLReader?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that's the source of the error? The error message is complaining about line 5.

It rather looks like you've created a tag name that starts with `xml` which is [illegal according to the XML specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-common-syn):

> Names beginning with the string `"xml"`, or with any string which would
>   match `(('X'|'x') ('M'|'m') ('L'|'l'))`, are reserved for
>   standardization in this or future versions of this specification.